# Barbox with arrows

Tags: r, plot

I want create a bar graph and add confidence interval. I'm using 'boxplot + arrows'. However, there is an error alignment between boxplot and arrows.

My dataset

```
$ df <- read.csv("database.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
$ df

# df is 'data frame'
# Gives mean and confidence interval (ci)

                   method      mean          ci
4                       A 0.3873552 0.002879887
6                       B 0.3873552 0.002879887
11                      C 0.3873552 0.002879887
12                      D 0.3873552 0.002879887
10                      E 0.3757940 0.005424378
1                       F 0.3715910 0.001226391
3                       G 0.3642126 0.010307811
5                       H 0.3615370 0.001347359
9                       I 0.3589878 0.002041493
13                      J 0.3585191 0.006083269
2                       K 0.3570351 0.002684985
7                       L 0.3497304 0.015632625
8                       M 0.2994054 0.001846430
```

R code:

```
result <- df

barplot(result$modularity, names=result$method, space = 0.3,  main = "Title", las=0.8, cex.names=0.8, ylab="y label", ylim = c(0.2,0.5),yaxp=c(0.2,0.5,10), xpd=F)

names = result$method
x = 1:13*2-1
CI.up = as.numeric(result$modularity)+as.numeric(result$ci)
CI.dn = as.numeric(result$modularity)-as.numeric(result$ci)
arrows(x,CI.dn,x,CI.up,code=3,length=0.06,angle=90,col='black')
```

RESULT: There is an error alignment between boxplot and arrows. Does anyone know the error?

[image]

I want this result:

[image]

RESULT: There is an error alignment between boxplot and arrows. Does anyone know the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`barplot` does not default to plotting the bars on integer x values (*i.e.* not on 1, 2, ...).  You can get the x values out of barplot by setting `x <- barplot()`.

Try the following:

```
x <- barplot(result$modularity, ...)
arrows(x,CI.dn,x,CI.up,code=3,length=0.06,angle=90,col='black')
```

Comment: @thelatemail: Yes!  I have corrected my mistake in the answer